# Bootstrap tabs postback on grid view page change

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-tabs

I am having an issue with the active tab staying when changing pages on the grid view within the tab panel.

Below is the code i currently have

ASP Front END

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadingContent" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblstudentsHeading" runat="server" Text="Students">
</asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="Tabs" role="tabpanel">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active"><a href="#membership" aria-controls="membership" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Installment Packages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lesson" aria-controls="lesson" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">10 Lesson Block</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Casual" aria-controls="Casual" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Casual</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content ">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="membership">
                <asp:GridView ID="gv_StudentProgress" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" OnRowDataBound="gv_StudentProgress_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="gv_StudentProgress_PreRender" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_StudentProgress_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="View"
                                    Visible='<%# HideViewButton((int)Eval("StateID")) %>'
                                    CommandName="View Progress"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave"
                                    ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                                    OnClick="btnViewProgress_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Edit"
                                    Visible='<%# HideEditButton((int)Eval("StateID")) %>'
                                    CommandName="Edit Progress"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave"
                                    ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                                    OnClick="btnEditProgress_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Frofeit" HeaderText="Frofeit" SortExpression="Frofeit" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forfiet">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="false"
                                    Checked='<%# ForfeitChk((int)Eval("Frofeit")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reschedule" HeaderText="Reschedule" SortExpression="Reschedule" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reschedule">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="false"
                                    Checked='<%# RescheduleChk((int)Eval("Reschedule")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StateID" HeaderText="StateID" SortExpression="StateID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="true"
                                    Text='<%# State((int)Eval("StateID")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReliefTeacherID" HeaderText="ReliefTeacherID" SortExpression="ReliefTeacherID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Relief Teacher">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server"
                                    Text='<%# ReliefTeacher((int)Eval("ReliefTeacherID")) %>'
                                    Visible='<%# HideReliefTeacher((int)Eval("ReliefTeacherID")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="WarmUp" HeaderText="Warm Up" SortExpression="WarmUp" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Excercises" HeaderText="Excercises" SortExpression="Excercises" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Technique" HeaderText="Technique" SortExpression="Technique" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentSongs" HeaderText="Current Songs" SortExpression="CurrentSongs" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LessonNotes" HeaderText="Lesson Notes" SortExpression="LessonNotes" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SelectStudentProgressAll" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="StudentID" SessionField="Progress" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlGVAdd" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddStudentProgressMembership" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddStudentProgressMembership_Click" Text="Add Student Progress" CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave" />
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="lesson">
                <asp:GridView ID="gv_StudentProgress10lesson" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" OnRowDataBound="gv_StudentProgress10lesson_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="gv_StudentProgress10lesson_PreRender" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_StudentProgress10lesson_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="View"
                                    Visible='<%# HideViewButton((int)Eval("StateID")) %>'
                                    CommandName="View Progress"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave"
                                    ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                                    OnClick="btnViewProgress_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Edit"
                                    Visible='<%# HideEditButton((int)Eval("StateID")) %>'
                                    CommandName="Edit Progress"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave"
                                    ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                                    OnClick="btnEditProgress_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Frofeit" HeaderText="Frofeit" SortExpression="Frofeit" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forfiet">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="false"
                                    Checked='<%# ForfeitChk((int)Eval("Frofeit")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reschedule" HeaderText="Reschedule" SortExpression="Reschedule" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reschedule">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="false"
                                    Checked='<%# RescheduleChk((int)Eval("Reschedule")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StateID" HeaderText="StateID" SortExpression="StateID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="true"
                                    Text='<%# State((int)Eval("StateID")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReliefTeacherID" HeaderText="ReliefTeacherID" SortExpression="ReliefTeacherID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Relief Teacher">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server"
                                    Text='<%# ReliefTeacher((int)Eval("ReliefTeacherID")) %>'
                                    Visible='<%# HideReliefTeacher((int)Eval("ReliefTeacherID")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="WarmUp" HeaderText="Warm Up" SortExpression="WarmUp" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Excercises" HeaderText="Excercises" SortExpression="Excercises" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Technique" HeaderText="Technique" SortExpression="Technique" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentSongs" HeaderText="Current Songs" SortExpression="CurrentSongs" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LessonNotes" HeaderText="Lesson Notes" SortExpression="LessonNotes" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SelectStudentProgressAll10Lesson" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="StudentID" SessionField="Progress" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddStudentProgress10Lesson" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddStudentProgress10Lesson_Click" Text="Add Student Progress" CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave" />
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Casual">
                <asp:GridView ID="gv_StudentProgressCasual" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" OnRowDataBound="gv_StudentProgressCasual_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="gv_StudentProgressCasual_PreRender" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_StudentProgress10lesson_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="View"
                                    Visible='<%# HideViewButton((int)Eval("StateID")) %>'
                                    CommandName="View Progress"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave"
                                    ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                                    OnClick="btnViewProgress_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Edit"
                                    Visible='<%# HideEditButton((int)Eval("StateID")) %>'
                                    CommandName="Edit Progress"
                                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave"
                                    ButtonType="Button"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'
                                    OnClick="btnEditProgress_Click" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Frofeit" HeaderText="Frofeit" SortExpression="Frofeit" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Forfiet">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="false"
                                    Checked='<%# ForfeitChk((int)Eval("Frofeit")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Reschedule" HeaderText="Reschedule" SortExpression="Reschedule" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reschedule">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="false"
                                    Checked='<%# RescheduleChk((int)Eval("Reschedule")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="StateID" HeaderText="StateID" SortExpression="StateID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Visible="true"
                                    Text='<%# State((int)Eval("StateID")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReliefTeacherID" HeaderText="ReliefTeacherID" SortExpression="ReliefTeacherID" Visible="false" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Relief Teacher">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server"
                                    Text='<%# ReliefTeacher((int)Eval("ReliefTeacherID")) %>'
                                    Visible='<%# HideReliefTeacher((int)Eval("ReliefTeacherID")) %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="WarmUp" HeaderText="Warm Up" SortExpression="WarmUp" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Excercises" HeaderText="Excercises" SortExpression="Excercises" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Technique" HeaderText="Technique" SortExpression="Technique" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CurrentSongs" HeaderText="Current Songs" SortExpression="CurrentSongs" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LessonNotes" HeaderText="Lesson Notes" SortExpression="LessonNotes" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" SelectCommand="SelectStudentProgressAllCasual" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="StudentID" SessionField="Progress" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
                </asp:Panel>
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddStudentProgressCasual" runat="server" OnClick="btnAddStudentProgressCasual_Click" Text="Add Student Progress" CssClass="btn btn-defaultactionsave" />
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="TabName" runat="server" />   
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedTab = $("#<%=TabName.ClientID%>");
        var tabId = selectedTab.val() != "" ? selectedTab.val() : "membership";
        $('#dvTab a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
        $("#dvTab a").click(function () {
            selectedTab.val($(this).attr("href").substring(1));
        });
    });
</script>
```

C# code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string studentid = Session["Progress"].ToString();
            string studentsName = Session["studentsName"].ToString();
            lblstudentsHeading.Text = "View Progress for " + studentsName;
            StudentsTableAdapter sta = new StudentsTableAdapter();
            membershiptype = sta.SelectStudentMembership(Convert.ToInt32(studentid)).ToString();
            if (Session["ViewALL"].ToString() == "1")
            {
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SelectStudentProgressAll";
                SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SelectStudentProgressAll10Lesson";
                SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "SelectStudentProgressAllCasual";
                gv_StudentProgress10lesson.DataBind();
                gv_StudentProgressCasual.DataBind();
                gv_StudentProgress.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Session["ViewALL"] = "0";
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("ViewStudnetReport.aspx -> Page_Load : " + ex.Message, ex);
        }
}

protected void gv_StudentProgress_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        TabName.Value = "#membership";
    }
    protected void gv_StudentProgressCasual_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        TabName.Value = "#Casual";
    }
    protected void gv_StudentProgress10lesson_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        TabName.Value = "#lesson";
    }
```

any thoughts on why the active tab doesnt get set to the page that it is on before the post back

Comment: I see where you read from a hidden field to get the currently-selected tab, but do you ever actually update the value of that hidden field after changing tabs? (that would be required to preserve the current tab across post backs)

Edit: Scratch that, I see where you update the hidden field. Hmm...

Comment: The JQuery that tries to show the correct tab starts with `$('#dvTab `. However, I don't see any element in your markup with that ID. Assuming there is no such element (and I'm not just missing it), that means that the `.tab('show');` at the end of that line won't run on any elements (since there would be no match).

Comment: no this didnt work.

i have changed the jquery to the following 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var tabName = $("[id*=TabName]").val() != "" ? $("[id*=TabName]").val() : "personal";
$('#Tabs a[href="#' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
$("#Tabs a").click(function () {
    $("[id*=TabName]").val($(this).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
});
});

    </script>

Comment: You are rebinding your grid on each postback. In your page load add try catch inside if(!Page.IsPostback){ } .